# How to calculate rise in of the vectors in 3D which are tilted?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, 3d, trigonometry

I have a data, which shows coordinates for start and end of the vectors in 3D space which are orientated around 3-fold screw axis:

```
            x          y           z
0   38.522003   5.600998  129.203995  # start of v1
1   23.854996  66.576996  112.487000  # end of v1
2    4.417000  40.182999  121.309998  # start of v2
3   65.761993  27.550995  104.285004  # end of v2
4   50.272003  56.473999  112.857010  #...
5   12.574997   6.202995   96.598007
6   45.192993   8.042999  105.147995
7   15.934998  63.490005   88.347992
8    3.613998  33.112991   97.102997
9   66.244003  35.949997   80.309006
10  44.052994  59.996002   89.057999
11  19.916000   2.125000   72.294998
12  51.201996  11.974998   81.044998
13   9.035995  58.367996   64.238998
14   4.529999  25.854996   72.759003
15  64.563004  44.283997   56.357998
16  37.153000  62.003998   65.026001
17  28.061996   0.000000   48.126995
```

Which looks like this:
[image: Representation of vectors in space]

```
for i in range(xyz_coords.shape[0]):
    if i == 0:
        ax.plot(xyz_coords['x'].loc[0:1], xyz_coords['y'].loc[0:1], xyz_coords['z'].loc[0:1])
    elif i%2 == 0 and i!=0:
        ax.plot(xyz_coords['x'].loc[i:i+1], xyz_coords['y'].loc[i:i+1], xyz_coords['z'].loc[i:i+1])
```

I would like to calculate the rise and angle between each starting and ending positions of the vector in relation to the next one, and those values should be similar for each vn and vn+1. The problem is that vectors shifts are not parallel to the z axis - otherwise it would be very simple task to determine the rise. The distance between v1(start) and v2(start) gives me the distance between them. Loading the data given above as pandas DataFrame, the distance between the starting points of v1 and v2:

```
d = np.sqrt((xyz_coords['x'][0] - xyz_coords['x'][2])**2 + (xyz_coords['y'][0] - xyz_coords['y'][2])**2 + (xyz_coords['z'][0] - xyz_coords['z'][2])**2)
```

You might also notice, that the z difference is ~8.95 but as as said before, z-difference is not proper rise value because is influenced by the tilt. If I knew how to determine the tilt angle I would be able to calculate the rise by just using `z_prop = sin(tilt_angle) * d`. Is there any easy way to correct the tilt and get the proper z value?

Comment: Maybe it is me, but I didn't get, what your expected output is. Could you provide your anticipated output for the first three vectors?

Comment: You can imagine this as Leaning Tower of Pisa: you want to calculate the distance between windows (v1(start) to v2(start)) but because tower is tilted you cannot use the z axis value difference because the distance will be smaller than the real distance. Now I have something like this tower which is tilted and has windows in different directions but they are not just above each other but rotated every ~120 degrees and moved by rise.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any easy solution to this problem. In my opinion, you will have to set up a system of 6 non-linear equations to solve for 3 rotation angles and 3 translation amounts, assuming that your vector undergoes a rigid body rotation and translation to give the position of the next vector. We can use `scipy.optimize.fsolve` to solve the non-linear system. Once you get the rotation angles you can find the tilt with respect to z-axis. But the code is not trivial and hence I will not be able to write all of it here.